# Any way to hook up an item sorter to expandable storage?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I already have a medium sized item sorting and storage system, using the common hopper filters method. Right now I have about 6 chests per item, and I'm wondering if there's a way to make the storage expandable without tearing things out.

I know about silos, but if I expand down, my final output chest moves down. If I expand up, I have to rip up the filter system and raise it as well.

Are there any good horizontal storage systems that are tileable, or ways of using a silo that lets you refill chests upward?

Comment: For moving items upwards: Minecarts with Hoppers are slow to transfer items, but allow for upwards movement of items. An item elevator + water stream to a hopper might also work, but it would probably be laggy.

Comment: Droppers can be used to make an item elevator. http://www.minecraft101.net/redstone/dropper-elevator.html

Comment: I believe items can rise through hoppers so if you hook up an dropper pointing upwards into a column of hoppers it should fill all of the up.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if this will help, but I think I found a good horizontal storage system. This one is infinitely expandable, and has an optional lamp that will light when the chest is full.

Seems to be what you need.

Comment: Hi @Apthree - constructive criticism is one of the best ways of learning how to be a better Stack Exchange user. The video you linked might answer the question but it is not acceptable to just post a video or a link - please try and explain what the video is showing, otherwise your answer becomes subject to link rot - if the video ever goes away, the answer is then useless. Read [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) about writing a good answer.